# Lyx: References not available

Tags: lyx, citing

I am using Mendeley to compile my references and papers.  I export automatically a .bib file for the folder in question and it appears and updates seemingly perfectly.

However, with a List/TOC--->BibTex Bibliography--->MyBIBFile.bib inserted some of the papers just don't seem to show up when I try to add the citations.  Sometimes they appear, sometimes they disappear.  Some are constantly working and never give problems.

When I open the .bib files in question in JabRef the articles not appearing are highlighted peach/red on the left hand side with respect to the number they are.   Not quite sure how to remedy that or whether it would make a difference but I doubt it is co-incidence.

Comment: In JabRef, certain things are *required*, otherwise the entry is highlighted. For example, you need an author if it's an article or a book. The entries you mention that are highlighted, are they missing some content?

Comment: Can you please make a minimal example (.bib and .lyx files, they are just text so you can copy/paste them into code here): http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Answer (score 2):

Solved on my own.  There was a discrepancy in some of the actual authors names and the bibtexkeys which were generated for the .bib file exported from Menedeley Desktop..... so I thought they were not showing.